# adding/sorting with hasmaps

Tags: java, text, hashmap

I have been given a text file with for a winter Olympic event.
It contains team, name of competitor and score.

```
FRAMae Berenice MEITE         455.455
CHNKexin ZHANG                454.584
UKRNatalia POPOVA             453.443
GERNathalie WEINZIERL         452.162
RUSEvgeny PLYUSHCHENKO        191.399
CANPatrick CHAN               189.718
CHNHan YAN                    185.527
CHNCheng & Hao                271.018
ITAStefania & Ondrej          270.317
USAMarissa & Simon            264.256
GERMaylin & Daniel            260.825
FRAFlorent AMODIO             179.936
GERPeter LIEBERS              179.615
ect....
```

The only digit that maters is the last digit in the number. 
for each team, I need to sum their total points together and display the top 5 teams.

Code so far:

```
public class project2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] array = new String[41];
    String[] info = new String [41];
    String[] stats = new String[41];    
    String[] team = new String[41];

            //.txt file location
            FileInput fileIn = new FileInput(); 
            fileIn.openFile("C:\\Users\\O\\Desktop\\turn in\\team.txt");

            int i=0;
            String line = fileIn.readLine();
            array[i] = line; i++;
            while (line != null) { 

                line = fileIn.readLine();
                array[i] = line; i++;
            }





            //Splitting up Info/ Score into two arrays

            for (int j =0; j< 40; j++){
                team[j] = array[j].substring (0, 3).trim ();
                info[j] = array[j].substring (3, 30).trim ();
                stats[j] = array[j].substring (36).trim ();
            }



            double[] statsDub = new double[41];
            for (int k =1; k < 40; k++){
            statsDub[k] = Double.parseDouble(stats[k]);
            }
            Map<String,Double> totalScore = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j =0; j< 40; j++){
                totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]);
            }
             // Get a set of the entries
              Set set = totalScore.entrySet();
              // Get an iterator
              Iterator i1 = set.iterator();
              // Display elements
              while(i1.hasNext()) {
                 Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i1.next();
                 System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
                 System.out.println(me.getValue());
              }
```

Prints out:

```
GER: 5.0
USA: 7.0
ITA: 6.0
RUS: 8.0
CHN: 1.0
JPN: 8.0
FRA: 7.0
CAN: 6.0
UKR: 2.0
GBR: 1.0
```

This is printing out only one score for each team. Any recommendation on how to sum the scores for each team?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here if the fix, try that:

```
 Map<String,Double> totalScore = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j =0; j< 40; j++){
    Double tmp = totalScore.get (team[j]);
    if (tmp != null)
    {
        totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]+tmp);
    }
    else
            totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]);
        }
```

this line: totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]);  only puts values not adding therefor you'll only have the last score per key.

Here is a working sample with the code I've posted above:

```
    package pkg;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class pkg
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] array = {
            "FRAMae Berenice MEITE         455.455",
            "CHNKexin ZHANG                454.584",
            "UKRNatalia POPOVA             453.443",
            "GERNathalie WEINZIERL         452.162",
            "RUSEvgeny PLYUSHCHENKO        191.399",
            "CANPatrick CHAN               189.718",
            "CHNHan YAN                    185.527",
            "CHNCheng & Hao                271.018",
            "ITAStefania & Ondrej          270.317",
            "USAMarissa & Simon            264.256",
            "GERMaylin & Daniel            260.825",
            "FRAFlorent AMODIO             179.936",
            "GERPeter LIEBERS              179.615"};
    String[] info = new String [13];
    String[] stats = new String[13];    
    String[] team = new String[13];




            //Splitting up Info/ Score into two arrays

            for (int j =0; j< 13; j++){
                team[j] = array[j].substring (0, 3).trim ();
                info[j] = array[j].substring (3, 30).trim ();
                stats[j] = array[j].substring (36).trim ();
            }



            double[] statsDub = new double[13];
            for (int k =1; k < 13; k++){
            statsDub[k] = Double.parseDouble(stats[k]);
            }
            Map<String,Double> totalScore = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j =0; j< 13; j++){

                  Double tmp = totalScore.get (team[j]);
                    if (tmp != null)
                    {
                        totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]+tmp);
                    }
                    else
                            totalScore.put(team[j], statsDub[j]);




            }
             // Get a set of the entries
              Set set = totalScore.entrySet();
              // Get an iterator
              Iterator i1 = set.iterator();
              // Display elements
              while(i1.hasNext()) {
                 Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i1.next();
                 System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
                 System.out.println(me.getValue());
              }
}
}
```

Output:

RUS: 9.0
CAN: 8.0
USA: 6.0
FRA: 6.0
GER: 12.0
ITA: 7.0
CHN: 19.0
UKR: 3.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I get the error "The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null" for the 4th line of code

Comment: I've edited the answer, change double to Double. I had a little typo.

Comment: I cant believe I didn't notice that typo. but it don't seem to be working properly. It just prints out 0's for every team. I will try and debug it, but if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to print out the top 5 teams.

Comment: Good :) you can press the up vote for the answer. and post a new question. top 5 shouldn't be a problem to find.

Comment: I marked it as the answer, but i cant upvote because I don't have the required rep.

Comment: :) I'll give you a hint for the next problem: you need to iterate trough the Map, Keep top 5 scores at an Array for example, and keep an index of the lowest score.